# lxml Memory allocation failed

Tags: python, xml, mongodb, pymongo, lxml

I'm using `lxml` for parsing. recently I got below issue(the code I have working fine). It may happen after using new release of `lxml` and `pymongo`. installing old package also did't help

```
parser error : Memory allocation failed
parser error : Memory allocation failed
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "src\lxml\xmlerror.pxi", line 87, in lxml.etree._LogEntry._setError
```

In debugging I find out there is big data to need to handle with `pymongo` and followings are stacked called and stuck there!
Can anyone help me for this issue?
Is there any way to increase memory used for this code. (if it is the case)

[image]

**Adding information:**

I make the code `exe` by `auto-py-to-exe` and it worked! no error!

Comment: Without any information beyond “memory allocation fails” it’s difficult to see how anyone can help you. The most basic information like the versions you are using, how “big” the xml file is, how much RAM your PC has, ...

Comment: @barny xml file is 240 M and I have tried different version of packages(`lxml==4.3.1`,`pymongo==3.8.0` and `pandas==0.24.2`). tested on on 64G RAM too

Comment: Those aren’t the only versions in what you’re doing. And OS? is it x64? And Python? Is that x64 too? Now please edit your code as a [mre] into your question. I should be able to paste your code into a file and run it (because that’s the best way of finding out what’s going on)) without adding anything.  If something like pymongo isn’t a significant part of the problem then remove it from your [mre]. Does the XML pass validation?

Comment: Windows server OS x64, code is part of class which I should edit it to fit here, Virtual Envirement(venv) created with python 3.7.3

Comment: Keep the code as simple as possible to reproduce the problem: you might want to start with simply parsing the file into memory (i.e. no class) - after all, if that works then the problem isn’t memory allocation during parsing.

Comment: the code was working fine with out any problem, I got this after installing new pakages (I guess)